# Python minidom: list childnode attributes per parent tag

Tags: python, list, for-loop, attributes, minidom

I have,

```
<parent id="1">
    <child id="white"></child>
    <child id="red"></child>
</parent>
<parent id="2">
    <child id="green"></child>
    <child id="gray"></child>
</parent>
```

I need this output,

```
1 
 white
 red
2
 green
 gray
```

This is how I am doing it,

```
parent = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('parent')
for item in parent:
    child = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('child')
    child_id = child.getAttribute('id')
    for child_id in child:
        print child_id
```

Of course, I'm getting it wrong, but do not know how to loop through these parent ids and collect each list individually. I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

a = '<parent id="1"><child id="white"></child><child id="red"></child></parent>'
dom = minidom.parseString(a)

for parent in dom.childNodes:
    print parent.getAttribute('id')
    for child in parent.childNodes:
        print '  %s' % child.getAttribute('id')
```

Comment: I am getting an error, "Text instance has no attribute, 'getAttribute'"

Comment: Maybe your running xml string is in the wrong format. Try to put the whole string on 1 line to see what happen. but the idea is still the same :)

Comment: Yes, I realized your code works. However when I repeat the parent tag block it breaks. Same with the other code. I am parsing from a file. I have no control over the input file. It has duplicates and no indentation. It's being a pain.

Comment: That is because your xml string does not have the root tag. Before using the parseString, you should add another root tag to make the xml string valid (a = '...xml string ...'; a = '<root>' + a + '</root>')

Comment: Thai Tran, tks. Finally found it. I'll keep in mind your comments for the future, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are guessing code and syntax:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

s =  """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container>
<parent id="1">
    <child id="white"></child>
    <child id="red"></child>
</parent>
<parent id="2">
    <child id="green"></child>
    <child id="gray"></child>
</parent>
</container>
"""


xmldoc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s)

parent = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('parent')
for item in parent:
    print item.getAttribute('id')
    for child in item.getElementsByTagName('child'):
        print child.getAttribute('id')
```